# How to bypass the Firebase Database refresh in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

While I am currently in other activity if my database changes my app get me into the list view page which is as shown bellow:

I wanna know how to I stop refreshing the data while I am not currently looking at that activity
Operating Code

```
 DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("new");
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            //   Object key = dataSnapshot.getValue();
            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(ch) ) {
                Map<String ,Object> key = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.child(ch).getValue();
                sname = (String) key.get("sname");
             //   Log.v("ABCD ", "Value is: " + key.get("sname"));
                if(dataSnapshot.getValue() != null)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.sunny.new.Selectclass");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }  else{

                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder1.setMessage("Check your Code");
                builder1.setCancelable(true);

                builder1.setPositiveButton(
                        "Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                alert11.show();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.v("XYZ", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

At `onPause` method of your activity, remove your event listener. And add it at `onResume` method.

**Detail:**

Define your `DatabaseReference` and `ValueEventListener` as reachable variables because you are going to reference them at `onPause` and `onResume` methods:

```
ValueEventListener myValueEventListner;
DatabaseReference myRef;

// Below may be inside onCreate method:
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("new");
myValueEventListner= new ValueEventListener() {
    // your event listener logic here
};
```

Add & remove at onPause and onResume methods:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     myRef.addValueEventListener(myValueEventListner);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    myRef.removeEventListener(myValueEventListner);
}
```

Comment: Suppose my app has 3 screen [screen1 -> screen2 - > screen3 ] if i am at screen3 and on firebase database update then my app automatically move to screen1

Comment: If you want to open screen1, when you are at screen3 and database updated; you should also listen database update at screen3.

Comment: this is Actually Happenings I don't want this How do i prevent this

Comment: @ghost Why don't you removeEventListener when you don't want refresh changes?

Comment: When i at screen1 or any other screen then i need that Listener thats why